# Как передать открытый ключ на сервер

Tags: linux, ssh, администрирование

Использую ssh. Я сгенерировал пару ключей, проблема в том что я не понимаю как мне их передать на сервер средствами ssh?
Сижу на linux.

Comment: Можно по аникейски: вставить на пастебин какой нибудь, и стянуть его курлом (зайдя через пароль в первый раз).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Открытый ключ это набор символов. Если ваша задача автоматический авторизовываться на сервере по ключу, то нужно текст из pub ключа вставить под определенного пользователя на сервере в файл в директории пользователя ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Есть 3 варианта

**Первый через ssh-copy-id**

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub youruser@remote.server.host
```

**Второй через команду**

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -l user@remote.server.host ‘mkdir -p .ssh;touch .ssh/authorized_keys; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys;chmod 700 ~/.ssh;chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys’
```

**Третий через scp**

```
localhost$ scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub youruser@remote.server.host
localhost$ ssh youruser@remote.server.host
remote.server.host$ [ -d ~/.ssh ] || (mkdir ~/.ssh; chmod 700 ~/.ssh)
remote.server.host$ cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
remote.server.host$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```